# Who predicted the tenth red heifer will be prepared by the Messiah?

Tags: rambam, messiah

The Rambam stated that the tenth red heifer will be prepared by the Messiah:

> וְהָעֲשִׂירִית יַעֲשֶׂה הַמֶּלֶךְ הַמָּשִׁיחַ מְהֵרָה יִגָּלֶה אָמֵן כֵּן יְהִי רָצוֹן: [[Mishneh Torah, Parah Adumah 3:4]](https://www.sefaria.org/sheets/182229.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

Is he the originator of this prediction, and if not, what is his source?

Comment: See Mishnah Parah 3:5

Comment: @DoubleAA, that mishnah doesn't say anything about the tenth one.

Comment: It has to do with no more red heifer by the mashiach

Comment: If the Mishna says 9 done already, who do we expect is going to do the tenth? Mashiach himself isn't a kohein anyway so not literally him. @meir

Comment: @DoubleAA, without the Rambam's statement we'd think that maybe just the ashes of one or more of the previous paros adumos will be found when Moshiach comes.

Comment: @DoubleAA, a non-_kohen_ can slaughter it IINM so maybe he'll personally assist in the preparation (though personally I doubt it). That said, I haven't seen the _Rambam_'s language: maybe it precludes that kind of preparation, referring to burning or something. As usual, quoting what you're asking about would be helpful.

Comment: @DoubleAA, Moshe wasn't a kohen either, but the mishnah and Rambam still say ראשונה עשה משה, because he supervised its preparation.

Comment: In other places, the number 10 will take place in the Messianic Era. For example: Shir HaShirim with Targum (the tenth song), harp that will have 10 strings in Messianic Era (Arakhin 13b) etc.. See also the Kiryat Sefer on Rambam ad loc.

Answer (score 1):

Rabbi Avi Kahana from [Machon Hamikdash](https://har-habait.org/articleBody/32291) says in note 52 that what the Rambam writes in Para Aduma
3:4 that Moshiach will make the tenth Para Aduma has no source in Chazal, and is not in the Mishna Para 3:5.

> ומה שכתב הרמב"ם שפרה אדומה יעשה משיח, אין לכך מקור בדברי חז"ל, וגם
> לא במשנה פרה ג, ה. הרמב"ם לא כתב כן כהלכה פסוקה, אלא מתוך אמונה, כי
> היום יבוא משיח וממילא הוא שיכין אפר פרה אדומה.

Comment: https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=58670&st=&pgnum=91